# Blazor DI for Components

Tags: blazor

I wish to decouple the Component from my UI by using Interfaces. This will allow us to control what Component is rendered and allow us to swap out components quickly.

The idea was as follows

- Create an Interface IMessageComponent
- Get a Component to inherit the interface
- Service Register the interface to a Component
- Import the Interface and use on the Page

```
Program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMessageComponent, StandardMessage>();

...
Shared/StandardMessage.razor
@implements IMessage
<div>Hello world</div>

...
Index.razor
@inject IMessageComponent Message
<Message />
```

**The Problem**
I am not getting any complier errors, however, nothing is rendering from the Component.

1. Is this possible?
2. Is this is a good idea? (DI Components)

Comment: In fact, the `StandardMessage` must be a class that implements the interface. You will have access to the methods of your `StandardMessage` class in your component after injecting the interface in your component.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible?

No because the point of DI is to manage object instances.  You define a component in DI but there's no way to pass that instance into the Renderer.  The renderer is a specialist DI container.  It renders `RenderFragments` that define component objects i.e. types, not instances.  The renderer creates, manages, updates and disposes of component instances.

I can imagine a dictionary of interface/concrete class that uses dynamic component instances.  Is that what are looking for?